# Database implementation question?

Tags: database

consider a disk with a sector size of 512 bytes, 2000 tracks/surface, 50 sectors/track,

5 doubled sided platters, average seek time is 10 msec.

Assume a block size of 1024-byte is selected.

Assume a file that contains 100,000 records of 100-byte each is to be stored on the disk,

and NONE of the reocd can be spanned 2 blocks.

How many blocks are needed to store the entire file??

If the file is arranged sequentially on disk, how many surfaces are required??

Now, i have calculated that 10,000 blocks are needed to store 100,000 records.

But i am not sure how to find out the answer of the surfaces required.

I only calculated the capacity of track is 25KB

and capacity of surface is 50,000 KB

But I don't know how to calculate the number of surfaces...

Could anyone help me how to get the answer?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Where the heck did you find a hard drive with 5 platters in it?  1985?

Comment: How did you decide this question should be tagged "database"? To me, this seems like a question that might be better answered on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have a 3-dimensional disk (surface, track, sector) and say about "sequentially arranged file". Sequential order is applicable only on file system level. Consequently to answer your question it's necessary to know, how the OS arranges the clusters of the file system on physical disk.

Now, modern disks have smart controllers, which rearrange sectors internally. I.e. side 3, track 201, sector 48 is not a neighbor of side 3, track 201, sector 47 or sector 49.

Finally, your question doesn't seem to be programming-related, and [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) is probably a better place to ask.